# Script to remove oldest files of type in each directory?

Tags: bash

Much research has turned almost similar questions yet nothing close enough to give me an idea of how to accomplish part my task. I'll try to keep this clear and short, while explaining the situation and desired result. My structure would be as follows:

```
-mobile  
--Docs  
--Downloads  
--SomeFile  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-1_named-silly.txt 
----dont.touch.me.pdf
----leave.me.alone.png 
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-2_named-silly.txt  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-3_named-silly.txt <---- file to keep  
--SomeFileA  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-1_also-silly.txt  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-2_also-silly.txt
----dont.touch.me.either.pdf
----leave.me.alone.too.png  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-3_also-silly.txt  
----this.is.crazy_0.0.1-11_also-silly.txt <----file to keep
```

The first part of my script to find the .txt files ignores every directory that is constant in this working directory and prints them to a list (which is a completely ugly hack and most likely a hinder to the way most would accomplish this task) "SomeFileB and SomeFileC" could come along with the same file structure and I'd like to catch them in this script as well.

The idea is to keep the newest .txt file in each directory according to its time stamp which obviously isn't in the filename. The files to keep will continue to change of course. To clarify the question again, how to go about keeping the newest .txt file in each variable directory with variable crazy name, according to timestamp which isn't in the filename? Hopefully I've been clear enough for help. This script should be in bash.

I'm not with the current code right now, as i said its ugly but heres a snippet of what I have `find /path/to/working/directory -maxdepth 0 -not -path "*Docs*" -not -path "*Downloads* -name "*.txt" >list`

Comment: Do you have some code to show us? the `find` command is really good at this. As a start, try `ls -Art | tail -n 1`

Comment: Go to each directory, and do `rm` `ls -t | awk 'NR>1'`

Comment: Neither of these two suggestions pays attention to the requirements.

Comment: You're going to need to get your hands dirty with some bash scripting here. Since there's no obvious pattern you could fire your **find** against, you'd need to extract filenames which occur more than once, strip the trailing numbers off their ends and compare them in a loop to find the highest. Then delete those findings. And while you're at it, you better build some safety-switch in there to first show the files that are going to be deleted, and ask for affirmation.
But this you have to do yourself! Noone here will write your code for you!

Comment: Semi correct theory on what has to be done. Paying attention to the files structure shown, its obvious stripping trailing numbers doesn't apply here. Running a script on each specific directory to accomplish my task is easy, but would require me to edit it when SomeFileC and SomeFileD pop up, which would actually defeat the purpose of having a script. Running rm against an ls -t would get me the newest .txt file, Id like to keep the newest in each directory from one script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the question was understood correctly, the task could be expressed as:

**Recursively remove all files `*.txt` except the newest in each respective directory**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Find all directories from top of tree
find a -type d | while read -r dir; do

    # skip $dir if doesn't contain any files *.txt
    ls "$dir"/*.txt &>/dev/null || continue

    # list *.txt by timestamp, skipping the newest file
    ls -t "$dir"/*.txt | awk 'NR>1' | while read -r file; do
        rm "$file"
    done
done
```

Assuming this directory tree, where `a.txt` is always the newest:

```
$ tree -t a
a
├── otherdir
├── b
│   ├── d e
│   │   ├── a.txt
│   │   ├── b.txt
│   │   ├── c.txt
│   │   ├── bar.txt
│   │   └── foo.pdf
│   ├── c
│   │   ├── a.txt
│   │   ├── b.txt
│   │   └── c.txt
│   ├── a.txt
│   ├── b.txt
│   ├── c.txt
│   └── foo.pdf
├── a.txt
├── b.txt
└── c.txt
```

This is the result after running the script:

```
$ tree -t a
a
├── b
│   ├── c
│   │   └── a.txt
│   ├── d e
│   │   ├── a.txt
│   │   └── foo.pdf
│   ├── a.txt
│   └── foo.pdf
├── otherdir
└── a.txt
```

Change `rm "$file"` to `echo rm "$file"` to check what would be removed before running "for real"

Comment: thank you this is exactly the desired result from a much different direction than I was headed.